# Page Not Found error after reviewing an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing

After [reviewing this answer in the 'Low Quality Post' queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/33321), and then clicking on 'Recommend Deletion' selecting a comment, I get to this URL: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/112855/recommend-delete?delete-main=&fkey=40ef87016c8df76d1946073ffd62e27f

This is the screenshot of the page I get from that URL: [image].

I don't appear as a recent reviewer in the review queue, and it doesn't register that I have reviewed the answer when I revisit the [review URL of the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/33321), although the comment I selected has appeared. Trying to click 'Recommend Deletion' again, then not selecting a comment, still leads to the same 'Page Not Found' page. If I go back to the 'Low Quality Posts' queue through the [Review page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review), it still shows me the answer as if I never reviewed it.

Screenshot of the review page below. Notice that it still allows me to review the said answer even though the 'Recommend Deletion' comment I previously selected was already there:
[image]

My browser is Opera 12.14.

Comment: @Vaishali As of this moment, [the answer still isn't deleted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/112855/4797).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you! It is indeed a bug — it is fixed and the patch should be rolled out shortly.

See also [404 after recommending deletion in "Low Quality Posts" queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175230/).